# Possibility to pass dynamic value to template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

Is it possible to pass a dynamic value calculated before into a template in C++?
Like this:

```
array<double, INITIAL_SIZE_N * 5> arrayRef;
```

I just get that the expression needs a constant value error.

Answer (score 2):

Template parameters must be constant expressions, so that `array` has a fixed size determined when the template is instantiated during compilation.

If `INITIAL_SIZE_N` is a constant, then so is this expression, so it's fine. If it's a variable, then you'll get the error you describe.

If you want a dynamic array, use a dynamic array

```
vector<double> arrayRef(INITIAL_SIZE_N * 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Templates are compile time constructs.

Comment: Yes, but is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @MarcelHöll No there isn't.